# what is the use of running http over udp?

Tags: http, tcp, websocket, udp

I tumbled between udp and tcp over http. I have been looking into what is the real purpose of https://github.com/InstantWebP2P/node-httpp/wiki/An-introduction-to-node-httpp

Have became even more confused. What is the real purpose of running HTTP over UDP?.  The very nature of this UDP is that it can loose the packet, which may result receiving partial http data, and this makes no sense.

May be it will be more sensible once after i get explanations from SO.